# C# recursion in 'new' method

Tags: c#, new-operator

I have this code in my class MyClass:

```
public new MyClass this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (Count > index)
            {
                return this[index];
            }
            //...MyActions...
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In string...

```
return this[index]
```

... i have recursion, but i need use properties in **base** class.
I dont know how do it.

Example:

```
 return base.this[index]
```

But i dont may 'override' this method, only set 'new'. I sad

How do it?
Sorry my very bad english and thanks

Comment: If you're not allowed to **`override`** the indexer on the base class, that's because they didn't make the indexer `virtual`. They probably didn't do that for a reason. I think it's a dangerous idea to _hide_ the indexer with a `new` indexer with the same signature (`this[int index]`). It will be confusing with two indexers with the same signature. In most cases, don't use the `new` modifier for hiding memebers of the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword to access members of the base class including indexers. Try to use next code snippet to call indexer on base class:

```
return base[index];
```

Answer (score 3):

Then use `base` as desired:

```
return base[index];
```

For example:

```
public class A {
  public object this[int index] { get; }
}

public class B : A {
  public object this[int index] {
    get { return base[index]; }
  }
}
```